# Not sure how to reference stringArray in main thread

Tags: java, android, arraylist, contextmenu, selection

As you can see I've been chopping and altering snippets of code I've found all over the place, and it's taken ages!

I'm stuck on the context menu which isn't capturing the touch selection when an item is selected, and eclipse is showing an error which I'm not sure how to correct.

I'm not sure how to reference the array list in the main thread, I know how to do it if it's an array from a string, but not on main thread.

The line with ******* is the one that gives the error.

Just wondering if someone could take a peek at it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private ArrayList<Sound> mSounds = null;
private SoundAdapter mAdapter = null;
static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
this.getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.selector);
mSounds = new ArrayList<Sound>();
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Echoex");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.echoex);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Edge");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.edge);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Enterprise");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.enterprise);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Envy");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.envy);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Etcher");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.etcher);
mSounds.add(s);
mAdapter = new SoundAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, mSounds);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
Sound s = (Sound) mSounds.get(position);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, s.getSoundResourceId());
mp.start();

}@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
  }
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    ********String[] names = getResources().getString(R.array.mSounds);
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.setasnotification:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Applying " + getResources().getString(R.string.setas) +
                      " context menu option for " + names[(int)info.id],
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
    default:
          return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}}
```

Sound.java:

```
public class Sound {
private String mDescription = "";
private int mSoundResourceId = -1;
private int mIconResourceId = -1;
public void setDescription(String description) { mDescription = description; }
public String getDescription() { return mDescription; }
public void setSoundResourceId(int id) { mSoundResourceId = id; }
public int getSoundResourceId() { return mSoundResourceId; }
public void setIconResourceId(int id) { mIconResourceId = id; }
public int getIconResourceId() { return mIconResourceId; }
}
```

Comment: I thoroughly recommend learning, using many tutorials on the web, rather than copy/paste.  You will create better software faster.

Comment: Well if you don't want to post catlog, at least the post the error you are getting in detail.

Comment: It's not so much something that could be logged. I simply don't know what to put where it says "String[] names = getResources().getString(R.array.names);"

Comment: My list of items, as you can see above, is in the mainactivity, not in a string or string array

Comment: @SeanBurrage : please check Umer Farooq's reply. Your mSounds variable isn't instantiated for arraylist type. (he's quicker with the reply)

Comment: check for proper R file in your imports it should not be android.R, also check for "names" in arrays.xml , also I dont find mSounds = new ArrayList<Sound>() anywhere

Comment: mSounds = new ArrayList<Sound>() where do I put this?

Comment: @SeanBurrage directly after "this.getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.selector);" If you want i put an answer to explain why you have to do that.

Comment: Ok, thats done, but what about this line? "String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mSounds);"

Comment: Uhm, the parameter should be a XML file. I doubt that it's an xml file. Btw, your switch-code contains also errors.

Comment: I know this line is wrong as my list is on main thread, and not in a string. My list are those five sounds listed above, Echoex,edge, enterprise, envy and etcher.

Comment: what is the name of the string-array in arrays.xml file in res folder? is it mSounds?

Comment: no there is no string!!! The array is that list you see in the main thread

Comment: I've tried "String[] names = getResources().getArrayList(this, R.layout.list_row, mSounds);" but still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target parameter might be incorrect.

```
********String[] names = getResources().getString(R.array.mSounds);
```

I have a feeling that you are targeting the mSound, of `ArrayList<Sound>` type. That method doesn't work by this way. You have to create a XML-file if you want to use the above method. Here below is an example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>  
    <array name="myArray">  
        <item>first song</item>  
        <item>second song</item>  
        <item>third song</item>  
        <item>fourth song</item>  
        <item>fifth song</item>  
    </array>
</resources>
```

This is saved into a XML file, below **soundArray.xml**. Then you can use the above method as

```
String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.soundArray);
```

This should work.

### OR if you want to use the Sound objects

(it's not an android class?)
You have to loop through the list and return the string of the said sound object.

```
int length = mSounds.size(); // get the length of mSounds object
String[] names = new String[length]; // creates a fixed array with strings
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     // add sound name to string array
     names[i] = mSounds.get(i).getDescription(); // returns the string name
}
```

But if the `Sound` class is a custom class from you, you have to see if it contains a method which returns the name of the said sound item. If it doesn't (or if you don't have overwritten the toString()-method, it will return the reference address, something which you don't want to see...

Comment: So there's no way possible to reference the list thats in the main activity: mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Echoex");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.echoex);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Edge");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.edge);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Enterprise");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.enterprise);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Envy");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.envy);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Etcher");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.etcher);

Comment: @SeanBurrage updated the code. But you have to tell me what the Sound class is. It's not an android class. Perhaps a custom class ? I have noticed the setDescription()-method. Does this class have a **getDescription()**-method ?

Comment: yes it does: public class Sound {
private String mDescription = "";
private int mSoundResourceId = -1;
private int mIconResourceId = -1;
public void setDescription(String description) { mDescription = description; }
public String getDescription() { return mDescription; }
public void setSoundResourceId(int id) { mSoundResourceId = id; }
public int getSoundResourceId() { return mSoundResourceId; }
public void setIconResourceId(int id) { mIconResourceId = id; }
public int getIconResourceId() { return mIconResourceId; }
}

Comment: @SeanBurrage , just replace the toString() to getDescription() method. Updated the code. It should return you an string array with all description names.

Comment: Ok! Brilliant! Got it. Perfect That's works perfectly. May I ask, would you be interested in helping me if I paid you? As I'm only half done. I now need to try and figure out how to set the selection as a ringtone.

Comment: I'm sorry, (i even don't ask for payment), but completing your project is your own goal. This site is here to provide answers on code-related issues, not for full code guides. You can learn more if you try and write your own codes. Please use libraries or documentation to understand what Android can offer you. For example, [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) to obtain the selected item. And progress from there. Feel free to place new questions (**please use the search tool first**) if you have new problems. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
```

instead of

```
********String[] names = getResources().getString(R.array.names);
```

Comment: still shows error :(  The thing is I don't want to reference a string from resources, as my array is in the main thread, not in a string file

Comment: private ArrayList<Sound> mSounds = null;     I think that's the name of the ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 ********String[] names = getResources().getString(R.array.names);
```

to

```
 String[] names = getResources().getString(R.array.names);
```

You are also adding objects in `ArrayList mSound` without instantiating `mSound`. You should do like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

.....

    mSound = new ArrayList<Sound>();
```

then do

```
   mSound.add(s);

}
```

Comment: The author has mentioned that the error came from the line where he has placed the ****** sequence ...

Comment: Yes sorry the asterisks were only there to mark the line where I have the error.